# How to set AWS Container Credentials using AWS Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-java-sdk

I want to use `ContainerCredentialsProvider(CredentialsEndpointProvider)`
instead of `ContainerCredentialsProvider()`, as the latter is deprecated.

Currently I am using deprecated constructor `ContainerCredentialsProvider()` as below:

```
AWSSimpleSystemsManagement ssm = 
    AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder
        .standard()
        .withRegion(region)
        .withCredentials(new ContainerCredentialsProvider())
        .build();
```

`CredentialsEndpointProvider` is an abstract class. 
I need to use something like `ECSCredentialsEndPointProvider` in my docker and I am not sure how to do that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you use `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain` which makes sure that your container assigned role can be utilized.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Don't you have a cluster role?

Comment: it could be helpful for debugging for example...your counter-questions are definitely not helpful

Answer (score 12):

I know this is kind of late, but hopefully this will help others like me who came to this question even in 2020 :)

Using your code's example, you should try out this

```
AWSSimpleSystemsManagement ssm = 
    AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder
        .standard()
        .withRegion(region)
        .withCredentials(new EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper())
        .build();
```

The [EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper.html) implements AWSCredentialsProvider, and loads credentials from Amazon Container (e.g. EC2) Credentials, solving them in the following order:

> 1. If environment variable "AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" is
>    set (typically on EC2) it is used to hit the metadata service at the
>    following endpoint: http://169.254.170.2
> 2. If environment variable "AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_FULL_URI" is set it is used to hit a metadata service at that URI.
>    Optionally an authorization token can be included in the "Authorization" header of the request by setting the "AWS_CONTAINER_AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN" environment variable.
> 3. If neither of the above environment variables are specified credentials are attempted to be loaded from Amazon EC2 Instance Metadata Service using the InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.

This is similar to the deprecated
[ContainerCredentialsProvider()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/ContainerCredentialsProvider.html) :

> By default, the URI path is retrieved from the environment variable "AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" in the container's environment.

---

Update: If you are not sure which mechanism will be used or want to be compatible with environment variables, system properties, profile credentials and container credentials, you could use the [`DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html) which will make sure to try out all options (as @Imran pointed out in a comment):

```
AWSSimpleSystemsManagement ssm = 
    AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder
        .standard()
        .withRegion(region)
        .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
        .build();
```

For example, the implementation for the 1.11 SDK looks like this (it basically tries all the options until it finds one that works):

```
public DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain() {
    super(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(),
          new SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider(),
          new ProfileCredentialsProvider(),
          new EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper());
}
```

This way you are compatible with new versions that may introduce another type of authentication or if one option gets deprecated.

Comment: Helped a lot mate !

Comment: Very helpful. I was struggling for days to look for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you are meant to use the `EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper`:

```
val ecsCredProvider = new EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper()
```